# Breastfeeding on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, chazon-ish

Is there any halachic concern with breastfeeding on Shabbat? I believe the Chazon Ish brought down one can’t milk a cow on shabbos (which I disagree with personally), but under his logic would a similar issue present itself with breastfeeding from a human mother? I know technically, babies are not obligated to keep Shabbat, but would this be an issue of lifne iver on the mother’s part (at least according to the logic of the Chazon Ish)?

Comment: Everyone agrees cows cannot be milked on shabbat (in the standard way, collecting the milk for later, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admur 328:41 (ff.) rule that it is allowed.

> It is permitted without restriction for a woman to breast-feed a child on Shabbos, even if the child does not need to breast-feed such as if he is already satiated, or has formula or other foods available. (see [here](https://www.shulchanaruchharav.com/laws-relating-to-breastfeeding-and-breast-milk-on-shabbos-part-1/)).

The reason for this is because it is considered ["Derech Achila"](https://cor.ca/2015/04/the-kosher-status-of-vitamins-and-medicines/) (See Shulchan Shlomo 328:56 in name of Rav SZ”A; Piskeiy Teshuvos 330:1).

However, it is forbidden to squeeze the milk into a vessel. Pumping extra milk is forbidden (Orach Chaim 328:34 ff.), [due to the prohibition of melacha mefarek.](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachot_of_Nursing#cite_note-16).

So to [summarise](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachot_of_Nursing):

> According to Ashkenazim, it is only permissible to nurse on Shabbat if the infant feeds directly from the mother. A nursing mother who is experiencing pain may express excess milk if it goes directly to waste and is not collected in a cup or container.
>
> According to Sephardim, a woman who is nursing and the baby doesn't
> want to nurse, to avoid a lot of discomfort it is permissible to
> express the milk but it should go to waste immediately, such as
> nursing into a disgusting cup or onto the ground.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the mizrachi movement which allowed milking a cow on Shabbat would it be allowed to store in a cup if it will be drinken soon after? @shmuel

Comment: Is there any provision to do it for no reason? This implies engorged or pain is the minimum reason. What if it is simply for enjoyment or keeping the baby busy or putting the baby to sleep etc

Comment: Rav Auerbach is quoted in Me’or Ha-shabbat, Vol. I, pp. 504-505 in saying that this is allowed, only when the mother is in great pain or discomfort. The only way to do it, is to pump it into a sink or vessel, but to make sure there is a substance added to it, to render the milk "unusable". - Refer to here: https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/shabbat/dash-milking-shabbat

Comment: But if the mizrachi movement believed it is permissible to milk a cow on Shabbat why would this be any different from their POV @Shmuel

Comment: Where did you read this? It's clear in the Shulchan Aruch what the halacha is regarding to this.

Comment: @RabbiKaii The limitation on pain is only for expressing milk wastefully, which ordinarily would be rabbinically prohibited but we override that to avoid the pain. Straight nursing is always fine.

Comment: “ In the class, it was mentioned that he publicized his opinion to oppose that of Rabbis associated with the Mizrachi movement, who allowed Jews milking cows on Shabbos, and benefitting from their milk” https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130015/reasons-to-permit-milking-cows-on-shabbos @Shmuel

Comment: Note: the question is not about squeezing milk into a vessel, which your comment above and your reference are about. I note that the footnote on the ShulchanAruchHarav website which you brought as the Michaber reference from doesn't seem related to this question. I would recommend just quoting Admur 328:41? I haven't got time to follow the references right now. Secondly, the first half of the paragraph you quoted would be more pertinent to the question alá what @DoubleAA said. Just trying to be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Reb Kaii. I don't follow what you mean unfortunately. Please feel free to edit it, I am on my Ipad rn :)

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I put that first quote in directly from the website, but did not mean that this was a direct quote from the Shulchan Aruch though. But I see that it was a bit confusing for others! Great solve.